# Extracting element from table using selenium web scraping

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Using selenium I am trying to scrape a table from a website,
however, data appears compressed into one single column rather than two separate columns; `Date` and `Value`- help would be greatly appreciated - now amended to included further improvement

```
driver.get("https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-year/")

table_trs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="datatable"]/tbody/tr')

value_list = []
for v in range(len(table_trs )):
    value_list.append(table_trs [v].text)

print(value_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(value_list)
```

The table I am trying to scrape appears on the website as follows....

[image: table]

..and the section of html associated to it.....

[image: html tree]

Comment: And where is the code you wrote to scrape it?

Comment: I have updated question to show the code i've used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** *Answer is focused on correct usage of xpath and only based on your screenshot - Improving your question and posting code and examples as text would generate more specific answers*

To get the `<tr>`s of the table by `xpath` change it to `//table[@id="datatable"]/tbody/tr`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

table_trs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="datatable"]/tbody/tr')
```

### EDIT

Based on your improvements you can go with `pandas.read_html()` to convert the table directly into a dataframe. Just have to rename the columns, cause there are two span tag in the `<th>` that will lead to column name "Value Value":

```
driver.get("https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-year/")

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
df.columns = ['Date','Value']
```

As alternative you could iterate like this:

```
driver.get("https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-year/")

table_trs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="datatable"]/tbody/tr')
value_list = []
for row in table_trs[1:]:
    value_list.append({
        'Date':row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0].text,
        'Value':row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1].text
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(value_list)
```

##### Output

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Feb 4, 2022 | 37.18 |
| Jan 1, 2022 | 39.63 |
| Jan 1, 2021 | 34.51 |
| Jan 1, 2020 | 30.99 |
| Jan 1, 2019 | 28.38 |
| Jan 1, 2018 | 33.31 |
| Jan 1, 2017 | 28.06 |
| Jan 1, 2016 | 24.21 |
| Jan 1, 2015 | 26.49 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Thanks, but this provides a very strange output.... 
  `[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=.......`

Comment: It is a result set of the trs you have to iterate - As mentioned, improving your question would lead to more specific answers.

Comment: Iteration now added and converted to `df` but unable to split single column

Comment: Thanks for your update - I added an edit to my answer, take a look and give it a try.

Comment: that came out exactly as i'd hoped - thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing here or you put wrong xpath.
Valid xpath will be (based on picture) `"//div[@id="datatable"]/tbody/tr"`, but that will only give you the rows. You can iterate by getting the all row nubers and colums, something like `//div[@id="datatable"]/tbody/tr[i]/td[j]` and then get text fro each element.